# No "Location" header in JMeter for Auth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, jmeter, header, location

Auth 2.0.

"code" parameter is required to perform

POST /.../oauth2/v2.0/token

with code value.

In Fiddler code value could be found in Location header of response to /kmsi request:
[image: code in Fiddler]

However, here is no Location header in JMeter for the same request:
[image: no code in JMeter]

Why? Are there any tip to get Location header in JMeter too?

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing different response it means that

1. Either you're sending a different request. In this case inspect request details from JMeter and from the real browser using a 3rd-party sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Burp](https://portswigger.net/burp), identify the inconsistencies and amend your JMeter configuration so it would send exactly the same request as the real browser does (apart from dynamic values which need to be [correlated](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start))
2. Or one of the previous requests fails somewhere somehow, JMeter automatically treats HTTP responses with [status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400 as successful, it might be the case they are not really successful, i.e. you're continuously hitting the login page (you can check it by inspecting response data tab of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener). Try adding a [Response Assertions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved) to the HTTP Request samplers so there will be another layer of explicit checks of the response data, this way you will get confidence that JMeter is doing what it is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Thank you, Dmitri. I end up with access token and can use it for others end-points (even without code parameter), POST request in green (which should fail without actual code) is a trick with assertion status from your answer to another user.
What changes in configuration (v.5.4) could you recommend to implement?